# IF statement в mysql запросе

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if

```
$Query = "SELECT * FROM items 
          WHERE brand IN ('" . implode("','", $brand) . "') ".
          if(!empty($color)){
              AND color IN ('" . implode("','", $color) . "')
          } 
          if(!empty($style)){
              AND style IN ('" . implode("','", $style) . "')
          } ." ";
```

$brand,$style,$color - массивы со значениями,в том случае если они пустые тогда выражение не выполняется

Comment: А зачем вы вопросы дублируете ? и зачем вам это обязательно надо в одну строку писать. `$query="select ... where 1=1";` следующей строкой, отдельно `if( !empty($color) ) $Query.=" AND color IN ...";`

Comment: Прийдётся испозьзовать или if (как в коментрарии @Mike) или конструкцию ()? : типа `(empty($brand))? "": implode(,))`

Comment: А SQL запрос не поддерживает if, вместо там case when then else end используется. Поправьте шапку вопроса, иначе он выглядит некорректно.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM items 
          WHERE brand IN ('" . implode("','", $brand) . "') ";
if(!empty($color)){
    $query .= "AND color IN ('" . implode("','", $color) . "')";
} 
if(!empty($style)){
    $query .= "AND style IN ('" . implode("','", $style) . "')";
} ." ";
$query .= ';';
```

Answer (score 0):

1. А не пробовали `AND color IN` в скобки убрать? И далее по тексту.
2. Конструкция в целом у вас странная. Это же не вывод на экран, а конкатенация
3. Генерировать динамические запросы таким образом - очень плохо

**код**

```
$db = mew mysqli(данные для коннекта);

$brandWhere = 'brand IN ('.str_pad('',count($brand)*2-1,'?,').')';
$colorWhere = empty($color))?'':' AND color IN ('.str_pad('',count($color)*2-1,'?,').')';
$styleWhere = empty($style))?'':' AND style IN ('.str_pad('',count($style)*2-1,'?,').')';

$bind = str_pad('',count($brand)+count($color)+count(style),'s');
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE ".$brandWhere.$colorWhere.$styleWhere;)

$params = [$bind];
foreach($brand as &$e) $params[] = &$e;
foreach($color as &$e) $params[] = &$e;
foreach($style as &$e) $params[] = &$e;

call_user_func_array([$stmt,'bind_param'], $params);

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: *очень плохо*  -- боюсь, это никого не убедит. Расскажите, почему, или хотя бы приложите ссылку на рассказ.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```
class DbHelper {

    public static function attachBatchParams(&$query, &$binds, $placeholder, $values) {
        $placeholders = array();

        foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
            $parameter = "{$placeholder}_{$key}";

            $binds[$parameter] = $value;
            $placeholders[] = $parameter;
        }

        $query = str_replace($placeholder, implode(', ', $placeholders), $query);
    }
}

$binds = array();
$query = "  SELECT 
                * 
            FROM items
            WHERE 1 ";

if ($brands) {
    $query .= "AND brand IN (:brands) ";
    DbHelper::attachBatchParams($query, $binds, ':brands', $brands);
}

if ($colors) {
    $query .= "AND color IN (:colors) ";
    DbHelper::attachBatchParams($query, $binds, ':colors', $colors);
}

if ($styles) {
    $query .= "AND style IN (:styles) ";
    DbHelper::attachBatchParams($query, $binds, ':styles', $styles);
}
```

Такой код легче читается, Плюс на выходе получите query с готовыми placeholders и массивом параметром которые нужно будет приаттачить через bindParam

PDO
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

MySQLi
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Это сделает ваш код более безопасным.

**-- UPDATED --**

Автор думаю смог бы найти это по ссылкам из документации которые я указал, но специально для [**rjhdby**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/210178/rjhdby) добавил **пол страницы** кода

```
$db = new \PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test', 'root', '');

//Код указанный выше

$sth = $db->prepare($query);

foreach ($binds as $placeholder => $value) {
    $sth->bindParam($placeholder, $value);
}

$sth->execute();
```

Comment: И каким же образом данный код защитит от, например, SQL-инъекции?

Comment: А как по вашему зачем вообще существует функция **bindParam**. Случайно не для того чтоб отделать мух от котлет, когда запрос вначале подготавливается, а потом уже подставляются данные, которые не могут модифицировать сам запрос?

Comment: Вот если вы сейчас продемонстрируете, где в вашем коде bind_param, то я прям извинюсь. На первый взгляд никакой подготовкой запроса и данных у вас и не пахнет.

Comment: Placeholders будут содержаться в массиве **$binds**, обратите внимание что массив передаётся в функцию по ссылке для наполнения. Также как и **$query**, в которой placeholder будет заменён на массив placeholders. Можно конечно и через **?** как у вас, но именные мне нравятся больше, так как при отладке сразу понятно где какое значение будет. Конкретно самой функции, bindParam в коде нет, так как не ясно чем пользуется автор, и оставил приметку под кодом

Comment: Вы считаете, что автор **такого** вопроса догадается, что вы имели в виду, достигнет просветления и волшебным образом допишет еще с пол страницы кода для грамотного использования вашего **bind**'а? Тут нужен конкретный рабочий пример (ну может под **небольшую** доработку напильником) "от" и "до", иначе даже самые благие намерения не достигнут цели. Покажите, как пользоваться вашим кодом и, возможно, вас поймут и мир станет ближе к совершенству.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, вам необходимо добавить условия выборки. У вас есть два варианта решения:

1) Выбирать данные из базы, а потом в php(может быть любой другой язык) выполнять сравнение. Например в php, проверить что вам пришли данные из бызы: [is_null()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.is-null.php). А дальше уже  if, else, elseif или case... Смотри сами что вам будет удобнее использовать.

2) Выбирать данные, и [сравнивать их в СУБД](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Control_flow_functions.html). Например:

`SELECT IF (brand > 'ваше значение', brand, NULL) FROM items;`